# What state is contained in a WCF Client object?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Like the title says, I'm curious to know what state is contained in a WCF client proxy object - should I be new'ing up tons of these casually and not caring? Or are they more heavyweight and I shouldn't be so cavalier about creating them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much really - the link to the communication channel, it's state - that's about it. WCF tends to be very much stateless, so both your client and the server won't really hang on to a lot of state.

The cost of client-side proxy generation is two-part:

- first, there's a `ChannelFactory<T>` that needs to be created (where `T` is your service contract, e.g. `IMyService`). This part is fairly heavyweight, so if you can, cache the channel factory
- second, the channel factory is used to create the actual channel - this is quite a simple operation, and you shouldn't bother to cache this.

If you've used the `Add Service Reference` functionality in Visual Studio, or `svcutil.exe` on the command line, you usually end up with a `(YourService)Client` class - this basically encapsulates those two steps for you.

If you feel the urge to optimize, check out this two-step process and see if you can make it work for you, and if caching the factory (and thus limiting the number of factory instantiations) makes a difference for you.